# JS: Play sound in inactive OSX Safari tab

Tags: javascript, safari, howler.js

I have simple timer app which allows user to enable ticking sound - **one tick per second**.

I made it work for active & inactive tabs in **Chrome, Firefox and Edge**.

I am struggling with OSX Safari. No matter what I try, it mutes the sounds as soon as I switch to another tab. Interestingly, it does **not** mute the sound if I detach the tab and switch to another one. That's probably because the ticking tab is not directly visible, but is also not hidden.

What I use:

I'm **not** using `setInterval()`, because browsers tend to hibernate the main thread. Instead of that, I use simple Worker:

```
var worker = new Worker('/js/workers/IntervalWorker.js');
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    playStuff();
};
worker.postMessage('1000');
```

`IntervalWorker.js` looks like this:

```
var interval = null;
onmessage = function(e) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        postMessage('');
    }, parseInt(e.data));
};
```

`playStuff()` uses Howler library:

```
var snd = new Howl({
    src: [ '/blah.mp3' ],
    volume: 1.00,
});
snd.play();
// I have tried classic html5 audio tag, it makes no difference.
// Also please note that this is pseudo code,
// I DON'T actually create the Howl object every second
```

Do you have any tip or hack how to force **OSX Safari** to play sound while the tab itself is inactive?